# MongoDB DBRef list returning null in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql

Im trying to create a database in MongoDB using Spring Boot. I want to create two collections, a DbConnections collection and a Configuration collection. What I want to do is that each connection in DbConnections collection has it own Configurations, something as a SQL references using foreign keys. I have trying to do this using `@DBRef` annotation like this:

```
@Document(collection = "connections")
public class DbConnection {
    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "connection_sequence";
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String connectionUrl;
    private long fkIdUsuario;
    @DBRef(db = "configurations")
    private List<Configuration> configurations;

    public DbConnection() {
    }

    public DbConnection(String username, String password, String connectionUrl) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.connectionUrl = connectionUrl;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Configuration> getConfigurations() {
        return configurations;
    }

    public void setConfigurations(List<Configuration> configurations) {
        this.configurations = configurations;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConnectionUrl() {
        return connectionUrl;
    }

    public void setConnectionUrl(String connectionUrl) {
        this.connectionUrl = connectionUrl;
    }

    public long getFkIdUsuario() {
        return fkIdUsuario;
    }

    public void setFkIdUsuario(long fkIdUsuario) {
        this.fkIdUsuario = fkIdUsuario;
    }
}
```

And the Configuration class:

```
@Document(collection = "configurations")
public class Configuration {
    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "config_sequence";
    @Id
    private long id;
    private int fkIdConnection;
    private String name;
    private String query;
    private BasicDBObject values;
    private BasicDBObject result;

    public Configuration() {
    }

    public Configuration(long id, int fkIdConnection, String name, String query, BasicDBObject values, BasicDBObject result) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fkIdConnection = fkIdConnection;
        this.name = name;
        this.query = query;
        this.values = values;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public int getFkIdConnection() {
        return fkIdConnection;
    }

    public void setFkIdConnection(int fkIdConnection) {
        this.fkIdConnection = fkIdConnection;
    }

    public Map getValues(){
        if(null != values){
            return values.toMap();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setValues(){
        this.values = new BasicDBObject(values);
    }

    public Map getResult(){
        if(null != result){
            return result.toMap();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setResult(){
        this.result = new BasicDBObject(result);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

And I save the data like this in the controllers:
For DbConnectionsController:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/conexion")
    public DbConnection addConnection(@RequestBody DbConnectionModel dbConnectionModel){
        DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection(dbConnectionModel.getUsername(), dbConnectionModel.getPassword(), dbConnectionModel.getConnectionUrl());
        dbConnection.setFkIdUsuario(getIdUsuario());
        return dbConnectionRepository.save(dbConnection);
    }
```

And the Configuration controller save method:

```
@PostMapping
    public Configuration agregarConfiguracion(@RequestBody Configuration configuration){
        configuration.setId(sequenceGeneratorService.generateSequence(Configuration.SEQUENCE_NAME));

        return configurationRepository.save(configuration);
    }
```

Now, when I save a `Connection`, it doesn't have the field `configurations` in the mongo object, and when I create a new `Configuration` it stills doesn't show it in `DbConnection`.I try to fetch the DbConnections objects with a `GET` request, but the `configurations` field of `DbConnections` appears as null. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar issue with DBRef returning an array of nulls. A few steps that helped me diagnose:

1) Are your 2 collections `connections` and `configurations` saved in 2 separate databases? If not, you need to remove the `(db = "configurations")` after `@DBRef`.

```
@DBRef
private List<Configuration> configurations;
```

2) Are you able to find the objects when connecting directly into database? I use Robot 3T, a GUI tool to look into Mongo DB directly to examine the shape of data being saved. Make sure your `connections` are setup properly, you should also see the `configurations` for each `connection`, something like this:

```
configurations: [
  {
    "$ref": "configurations",
    "$id": ObjectId("asdfadsgasdfasdfa")
  }
]
```

3) You can single-step into class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver, method fetch(). (I am using springboot 2.1.6.RELEASE with spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency of the same version)

```
@Override
    public Document fetch(DBRef dbRef) {

        if (LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.trace("Fetching DBRef '{}' from {}.{}.", dbRef.getId(),
                    StringUtils.hasText(dbRef.getDatabaseName()) ? dbRef.getDatabaseName() : mongoDbFactory.getDb().getName(),
                    dbRef.getCollectionName());
        }

        StringUtils.hasText(dbRef.getDatabaseName());
        return getCollection(dbRef).find(Filters.eq("_id", dbRef.getId())).first();
    }
```

Make sure that all the properties (ie.collectionName, db, id) of `dbRef` are correct, otherwise it wont be able find the relevant object.